# How do I extract the parameters from a URL in Vim?

Tags: vimscript

If I type a URL and I want to extract the parameters from the query string quickly in VIM how would I do that?

For instance if I have:

```
http://www.somesite.org/page2014.html?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=eventlinkonwall&utm_term=trapshoot&utm_content=calendar_event_on_wall&utm_campaign=trapshoot2014
```

I want to end up with something close to:

```
utm_source=facebook
utm_medium=eventlinkonwall
utm_term=trapshoot
utm_content=calendar_event_on_wall
utm_campaign=trapshoot2014
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
df?:s/&/\r/g
```

- `df?` to delete everything up to & including the first `?`
- `:s/&/\r/g` to replace every `&` with a newline

You could prefix this with either `^` to go the start of the line, or `B` to go to the start of the word; use whatever is appropriate in the scenario. Be careful with automatically adding `B` in a keybind or command though, because if you're on the first character of the URL it will go to the word *before* the URL!

This will only work on well-formed URLs, the web would not be the web if there weren't a bunch of malformed URLs floating around ;-) Specifically, URL's which omit the `?` and just use `&key=value` to start the first parameter seem to be common.
To fix this, you could search for either the first `?`, OR the first `&`, which is unfortunately a bit more typing:

```
d/[?&]<CR>x:s/&/\r/g
```

The `<CR>` is the enter key.

If you do this sort of thing often, you could map it to a key:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>p df?:s/&/\r/g<CR>
:nnoremap <Leader>p d/[?&]<CR>x:s/&/\r/<CR>
```

Or make a command out of it:

```
:command! SplitURL exe 'normal df?'|:s/&/\r/g
```

Comment: Instead of `^` to go to the beginning of the line, you could use `B` to go to the beginning of the WORD.

Comment: Not all URL all perfectly formed. A **LOT** don't have the `?` character and just use the `&`. Browser automatically compensate (so you don't notice it much) but there are a significant number out there. So I would replace the `df?` with `d/[?&]<enter>x`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
:s/[?&]\ze.\{-}=[^&\r[:blank:]]\+/\r/g
```

It replaces all `?` and `&` (`[?&]`) with new line (`\r`) which are followed by `a=b` patterns ending with `&`, new line or space characters.

Where:

- `\zs` and `\ze` - Is the start and end of a pattern (these can be used independently).
- `[?&]` - Match either `?` or `&` character.
- `.\{-}` - Non-greedy quantifier which match as few as possible characters.
- `[^&\r[:blank:]]` - Match all characters which are NOT `&`, new line, space and tab characters.

Comment: Minor note: You can use `\zs` and `\ze` independently. In this case, the `\zs` can be omitted since it's at the start of the pattern already.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing this a lot of times, it's pretty quick to do it manually:

1. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>: Delete to the start of the parameters,
2. <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>&</kbd>: Jump to the next parameter
3. <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>: Replace the `&` with a newline,
4. Then just mash <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> repeatedly until you've separated all the parameters. (<kbd>;</kbd> jumps forward to the next occurrence of the last <kbd>f</kbd> command, and <kbd>.</kbd> repeats the last edit operation.)

Depending on how many parameters there are, it won't be many more keypresses that the answers already posted using `:substitute`, but, for me at least, it requires even less brainpower.